# Let $A$ be a $10 \times 15$ non-zero matrix. What are the possible values of the rank of $A$ and the nullity of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

So I think I understand ranks and nullity. I was thinking that the possible values of the rank of $A$ were $\le 10$. Then I thought I could calculate the possible dimensions of the null space by 
$$\mathrm{rank}A + \mathrm{dim (Null} \ A) = n.$$ 
And then:

$$10 + \mathrm{dimNul} \ A \le 15,$$

$$\mathrm{dimNul} \ A \le 5, \ \mathrm{nullity} \le 5$$

But maybe I'm completely off. Can someone help me out?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some good ideas. But your resulting inequality is the wrong way around. Consider if the matrix is only zeroes. Then the nullity is $15$, which just isn't what your inequality says. Rather, instead of $10+\text{nullity} \leq 15$ you should have $\text{rank} + \text{nullity} = 15$. Thus if the rank goes down, the nullity goes up.

You seem to think that because $\text{rank} \leq 10$, we can swap out $\text{rank}$ with $10$, but that is not right. Since we're swapping $\text{rank}$ with something which is potentially larger, but never smaller, we actually get
$$
15 = \text{rank}+\text{nullity} \leq 10 + \text{nullity}\\
5\leq \text{nullity}
$$

As for notation, note that nullity is the *dimension* of the *kernel*. So the nullity itself doesn't have a dimension, it *is* a dimension. Just like rank is the *dimension* of the column space (which is the same as the range of the corresponding linear map). So rank is a number, and thus doesn't have a dimension.

Answer (score 0):

A $10\times 15$ matrix represent a linear transformation from a vector space of dimension $15$ to a vector space of dimension $10$. Now $null(A)=\{v\in domain (A)~|~Av=0\}\subset domain(A)$. Hence nullity of $A$, which is the rank of the null space of $A$, can have dimension $\le15$. While the rank of $A$ is the number of independent columns of $A$. Note that the number of independent columns of a matrix is same as the number of its independent rows. Hence $rank(A)\leq 10$.